# Where can I find others callback of infinite grid store?

Tags: callback, grid, extjs4, store, infinite

I use an Infinite Grid, actually all work fine but in the PHP that the store uses I do a request to an external webservice.

This is my Store Load:

```
myInfGrid.getStore().load({
    scope   : this,
    url     : 'download.php',
    params  : { },                
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        if (success) {
            // Here a process is done only once time even 
            // for others automated launched requests
        }
    }
});
```

My download.php file contains a curl request to a webservice like below.
Sometimes the WebService takes a very long time to answer.

```php
    ...
    $url = "https://external_webservice";

    $params = array('callback' => $callback,
                    'q' => $query, 
                    'rows' => $rows,
                    'sort'  => $sort,
                    'start' => $start);

    $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);

    $myCurl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $fetchResult = curl_exec($myCurl);

    curl_close($myCurl);

    // HERE my process of $fetchResult content
    ...
```

I would like to extract this WebService Curl call and put it only on each callback.

My problem is: I don't know where are others callbacks.
I mean callbacks associated to all requests that are launched automatically by the infinitegrid ?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: Hi Eduardo, thanks for this info.

myInfGrid.getStore().load({
                    scope: this,
                    params: { 
                        //start   : '0'
                    },                
                    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                    
// FIRST CALL BACK - EXECUTED ONLY ONCE

                    }
....

Where can I find others callbacks ?

Comment: removed thanks and whitespaces.